# Is writing SO links into source code comments a good fashion?

Tags: discussion, linked-questions

Whenever I find a great solution for a critical issue and I use code snippets from Stack Overflow, I always feel the urge to write a comment that tells that "this answer/question provided the solution that the following code uses".

Is this fashion done by anyone else? Is it beneficial to do?

Consider the fact that I'm working on a hobby project only, so nothing official or actual work-related.

Comment: I think doing this prevents people from asking *why on earth did you do this* or *what proof do you have for this* ?. Yes, its beneficial. It saves a lot of time and *googling* :)

Comment: I'll do this when the answer on Stackoverflow goes into greater detail and depth of explaining an issue than I want to write in a comment. Usually I just write the gist of it in the comment and provide the link for further reading.

Comment: @TheLostMind the best type of link rot is link rot to useful information in code \o/

Comment: @PeeHaa link rot is quite rare on Stack Overflow, isn't it?

Comment: Very much not so. Questions and answers get deleted often.

Comment: @PeeHaa that is sad to hear, but makes sense. Do you think is there any methods to prevent it? for example, post the solution as a gist to GitHub, with a link back to SO?

Comment: Imo links to SO are fine for giving attribution for explaining what your code does not so much. Unless it really cannot explained in a comment. I'm writing code I don't want to go to random site x to find out why a piece of code does what it does.